# View Sketchup/CAD models in browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser, cad

I want a Sketchup/CAD model to be viewable in a browser (preferably Chrome). Given pitch, yaw, and roll measurements from a gyro, I want the CAD model to respond to the measurements. How would I go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is [Swift 3D](http://www.erain.com/) from Electric Rain, but I have no experience with it at all.